# Did the Flash actually visit his past?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, the-flash-2023

In the film *The Flash (2023)*, Bruce Wayne states:

> When you go back and change the past you create a fulcrum. You put yourself on a whole nother strand of spaghetti.

The Flash moves along the timeline, stops at some point, and then a fulcrum/timeline is created. Thus, something new.

Doesn't this mean that he never visits *his* past?

***Note:** I am only interested in the context of this movie and what it establishes, not the comics or other media.*

Comment: I'm not really sure how time travel works in these films, but in theory if you have branch off and time travel back then essentially both come from the same time line until the branch off. In Many Worlds Interpretation Theory the idea is that there is infinite of every combination of time lines, which means parts and all would have countless duplicates at some point -- so if you go by that logic anyone who has the same past part of their time line in a different universes is a moot argument because you have identical twins...

Comment: ...However in some sci-fi like Fringe or the Kelvinverse (see comic tie-ins) you may get some kind of reciprocity with ripple effects that go back further than the point of entry of the branch off(s). In Fringe Walter coins this as "The effect before the cause", but in that instance it was because some time line was being "written over" by the new existence of a former Peter Bishop. In star trek kelevinverse this reverse casualty is why Khan has diff set of genes/appearence. This stuff can get complicated depending on what canon/mythos one follows!

Comment: @DarthLocke My question is in the context of how the movie establishes how time travel works. Have you seen it yet (it's pretty good)? The dialog in the movie seems to alternate between traveling back and creating something new. If you're creating something new, you're not traveling back in your time but visiting this new reality. I suspect the mechanics were not thought out enough.

Comment: Like I mentioned, I have not, but was just commenting (and did not make an answer) on some other franchises/media and how they use time travel to offer possibilities (and why they do) in case you could figure it out by processes of elimination.

Comment: You didn't mention that you didn't see it, which is why I asked :) Thanks for the discussion points though! This movie tries to do things a little differently (of course).